# Update multiple charts simultaneously in d3.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I've created 3 different charts all drawn from the same dataset, 
my reasoning for building it this way is so that it'll be easier to add and remove  additional rows of charts.

What I'm mainly interested in knowing is if the code is well structured and/or if it's idiomatic d3 code.

Here's a link to all the code: [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/BPkh6FlZzGyZs7qyMsv8?p=preview)

And here's the same code but with hardcoded data:

```js
var durations = 0;

var z = d3.scaleOrdinal()
  .range(["orange", "steelblue"]);

var margin = {
  top: 35, right: 35, bottom: 35, left: 35, pad: 25
};

var csvData = 
`AgeRange,female,male,Woman_one,Man_one,Woman_two,Man_two,Woman_three,Man_three
"17 - 19",50,36,23,22,3,0,5,5
"20 - 24",145,99,80,72,22,3,27,14
"25 - 29",123,109,40,80,28,3,42,22
"30 - 34",121,52,54,35,21,2,32,13
"35 - 39",88,65,23,30,15,4,44,28
"40 - 44",79,52,28,22,8,4,40,23
"45 - 49",89,51,21,27,14,1,47,20
"50 - 54",67,31,15,12,10,1,38,15
"55 - 59",55,25,7,3,7,3,39,17
"60 - 64",40,21,5,5,4,2,30,14
"65 - 69",26,11,1,0,1,0,22,11
"70 - 74",10,6,0,0,0,0,9,5
"75 +",9,1,0,0,0,0,9,1`;

var dataSet = d3.csvParse(csvData)

row1(dataSet);

function row1(data) {

  var check = false;

  update(check);

  function update(check) {

    var team = d3.selectAll(".select1").property("value")

    data.forEach(function(d, i, columns) {
      d.male = +(d.male);
      d.female = +(d.female);
      d["Woman" + team] = +d["Woman" + team];
      d["Man" + team] = +d["Man" + team];
      return d;
    })

    if (check) {
      pyramid.update(data, team)
      percent.update(data, team)
      totals.update(data, team)
    } else {
      pyramid(data, team);
      percent(data, team);
      totals(data, team);
    }
  }

  d3.selectAll(".select1").on("change", function() {
    check = true;
    durations = 750;
    update(check);
  })

}

function pyramid(data, team) {

  var width  = 550 - (margin.left + margin.right);
  var height = 420 - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var x = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([(width/2) + margin.pad, width]),
      x2 = d3.scaleLinear()
        .rangeRound([(width/2) - margin.pad, 0]),
      y = d3.scaleBand()
        .rangeRound([height, 0]).padding(0.1);

  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x).ticks(6)
        .tickSize(-height),
      xAxis2 = d3.axisBottom(x2).ticks(6)
        .tickSize(-height),
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

  var svg = d3.select("#row1").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x hide")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x2 hide")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y")
      .attr("transform", "translate(" + (width/2 + 10) + ",0)")

  svg.append("text")
      .attr("x", width/2)
      .attr("y",  0)
      .attr("text-anchor", "middle")
      .text("Age");

  update(data, team);

  function update(data, team) {

    x.domain([0, d3.max(data, 
      d => Math.max(d.male, d.female))
    ]).nice();

    x2.domain(x.domain())

    y.domain(data.map(d => d.AgeRange));
    
    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--x")
      .call(xAxis);

    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--x2")
      .call(xAxis2);

    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--y")
      .call(customYAxis);

    function customYAxis(g) {
      g.call(yAxis);
      g.selectAll("text").style("text-anchor", "middle")
      g.select(".domain").remove();
      g.selectAll("line").remove();
    }

    // ==== Men bar ====

    var menTtl = svg.selectAll(".menTtl")
      .data(data).enter()
    .insert("g", ".axis--x")
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "M menTtl")
      .attr("opacity",.6)
      .attr("x", x(0))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.AgeRange))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("width", d => Math.abs(x(d.male) - x(0)));
    
    var menTeam = svg.selectAll(".menTeam")
      .data(data);

    menTeam = menTeam
        .enter()
      .insert("g", ".axis--x")
      .append("rect")
        .attr("class", "M menTeam")
        .attr("x", x(0))
        .attr("y", d => y(d.AgeRange))
        .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
        .merge(menTeam)
    
    menTeam.transition().duration(durations)
        .attr("width", d => Math.abs(x(d["Man" + team]) - x(0)));

    // ==== Women bar ====
    
    var womenTtl = svg.selectAll(".womenTtl")
      .data(data).enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "W womenTtl")
      .attr("opacity",.6)
      .attr("y", d => y(d.AgeRange))
      .attr("x", d => x2(d.female))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .attr("width", d => Math.abs(x2(d.female) - x2(0)));
    
    var womenTeam = svg.selectAll(".womenTeam")
      .data(data);

    womenTeam = womenTeam
      .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "W womenTeam")
      .attr("y", d => y(d.AgeRange))
      .attr("height", y.bandwidth())
      .merge(womenTeam)
    
    womenTeam.transition().duration(durations)
      .attr("x", d => x2(d["Woman" + team]))
      .attr("width", d => Math.abs(x2(d["Woman" + team]) - x2(0)));
  }

  pyramid.update = update;

}

function percent(data, team) {

  var width  = 150 - (margin.left + margin.right),
      height = 420 - (margin.top + margin.bottom);

  var x0 = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]),
      x1 = d3.scaleBand().paddingOuter(0.2),
      x2 = d3.scaleBand().paddingOuter(0.2),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
    
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x0),
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
    
  var svg = d3.select("#row1").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform", 
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
  
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y");

  update(data, team);

  function update(data, team) {

    var ttlKey = data.columns.slice(1, 3);

    var teamKey = ["Woman" + team, "Man" + team]

    x0.domain(["Women & Men"]);
    x1.domain(ttlKey).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);
    x2.domain(teamKey).rangeRound([0, x0.bandwidth()]);

    y.domain([0, d3.sum(data, function(d) {
      return d3.max(ttlKey, key => d[key]); 
    })]).nice();
    
    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);
    
    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--x")
      .call(xAxis);

    var barGroups = svg.selectAll("g.layer")
      .data(["empty"]);

    barGroups.exit().remove();

    barGroups = barGroups
      .enter()
    .append("g")
      .classed('layer', true);

    var bars = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll(".bars")
      .data(function() { 
        return ttlKey.map(function(key) {
          var sum = d3.sum(data, e => e[key] )
          return {key: key, value: sum};
        }); 
      }).enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "bars")
      .attr("fill", d => z(d.key))
      .attr("opacity", .6)
      .attr("x", d => x1(d.key))
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value));

    var barsTeam = svg.selectAll("g.layer").selectAll(".barsTeam")
      .data(function() { 
        return teamKey.map(function(key) {
          var sum = d3.sum(data, e => e[key] )
          return {key: key, value: sum};
        }); 
      });

    barsTeam.exit().remove();

    barsTeam = barsTeam
      .enter()
    .append("rect") 
      .attr("class", "barsTeam")
      .attr("fill", d => z(d.key))
      .attr("x", d => x2(d.key))
      .attr("width", x1.bandwidth())
      .merge(barsTeam);

    barsTeam.transition().duration(durations)
      .attr("y", d => y(d.value))
      .attr("height", d => height - y(d.value));
  }

  percent.update = update;

}

function totals(data, team) {

  var width = 110 - (margin.left + margin.right),
      height = 420 - (margin.top + margin.bottom);
  
  var x = d3.scaleBand().rangeRound([0, width]).padding(0.1),
      y = d3.scaleLinear().rangeRound([height, 0]);
  
  var xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x),
      yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);
  
  var svg = d3.select("#row1").append("svg")
      .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
      .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
    .append("g")
      .attr("transform",
        "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");
    
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--x")
      .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")");
  
  svg.append("g")
      .attr("class", "axis axis--y");

  update(data, team);

  function update(data, team) {

    var sum = d3.sum(data, d => d3.sum([d.male, d.female]));

    var sumTeam = d3.sum(data, function(d) {
      return d3.sum([d["Woman" + team], d["Man" + team]])
    });

    y.domain([0, sum]).nice();

    x.domain(["Total"]);
    
    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--y")
      .call(yAxis);
    
    svg.selectAll(".axis.axis--x")
      .call(xAxis);

    var ttlBar = svg.selectAll(".ttlBar")
      .data(["empty"]).enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "ttlBar")
      .attr("fill", "#ccc")
      .attr("x", x(["Total"]))
      .attr("y", y(sum))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .attr("height", height - y(sum));

    var ttlTeam = svg.selectAll(".ttlTeam")
      .data(["empty"]);
      
    ttlTeam = ttlTeam
      .enter()
    .append("rect")
      .attr("class", "ttlTeam")
      .attr("fill", "#999")
      .attr("x", x(["Total"]))
      .attr("width", x.bandwidth())
      .merge(ttlTeam);

    ttlTeam.transition().duration(durations)
      .attr("height", height - y(sumTeam))
      .attr("y", y(sumTeam))

  }

  totals.update = update

}
```

```css
body {
  font: 12px arial;
  margin: auto;
  width: 850px;
  padding-top:25px;
}
select {
  border: 1px solid #fff;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #ccc;
  cursor: pointer;
}
.M { fill: steelblue; }
.W { fill: orange; }
.hide path { 
  display: none; 
}
.hide .tick:not(:first-of-type) line {
  opacity: .25;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8">
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
<div style="margin-left: 25px;">
  <b>Choose Team:</b>
  <select class="select1">
    <option value="_one">Team 1</option>
    <option value="_two">Team 2</option>
    <option value="_three">Team 3</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div id="row1"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My answer here will focus on refactoring the `row1` function. Right now that's an awkward function, with some unnecessary logic.

Let's examine the it:

```
function row1(data) {

  var check = false;

  update(check);

  function update(check) {

    var team = d3.selectAll(".select1").property("value")

    data.forEach(function(d, i, columns) {
      d.male = +(d.male);
      d.female = +(d.female);
      d["Woman" + team] = +d["Woman" + team];
      d["Man" + team] = +d["Man" + team];
      return d;
    })

    if (check) {
      pyramid.update(data, team)
      percent.update(data, team)
      totals.update(data, team)
    } else {
      pyramid(data, team);
      percent(data, team);
      totals(data, team);
    }
  }

  d3.selectAll(".select1").on("change", function() {
    check = true;
    durations = 750;
    update(check);
  })

}
```

In the linked Plunker, which uses a real CSV, you get the result of the promise and pass it to the `row1` function. So far, so good.

However, inside that function, you're calling another function, named `update`, which gets the selected value of a `<select>` element. Then, based on that option, you're coercing only some values of the data array to numbers, but keeping the whole structure of the data array (you're not filtering or anything like that).

The `forEach` inside `update` is also strange: you don't need to return the object row. Also, the third argument, `columns`, is probably a reminiscent of the third parameter in the `d3.csv`: in a `forEach` method the third argument is not the array of headers.

Continuing, you're using a `check` variable (which is always `true` after the user changes the select) to choose what functions to call, and finally setting a listener to the select that never listens to the value of the select! It just calls `update` again...

This is my proposition to simplify this `row1` function:

```
function row1(data) {

    data.forEach(function(d) {
        for (var key in d) {
            if (key !== "AgeRange") {
                d[key] = +d[key]
            }
        }
    });

    pyramid(data, "_one");
    percent(data, "_two");
    totals(data, "_three");

    d3.selectAll(".select1").on("change", function() {
        durations = 750;
        pyramid.update(data, this.value)
        percent.update(data, this.value)
        totals.update(data, this.value)
    });

}
```

These are the changes:

1. The `forEach` coerces **all** the values, except for `AgeRange`;
2. You call the drawing functions with the data and the teams;
3. Since you know what values you're using for the first time, I just hardcoded them. If you don't like that just use another selection to get the selected option (again, hardcoded!)
4. You use the listener to get the value of the select with `this.value`, and call the update functions.

Also, if you put the drawing functions inside `row1`, you don't even need to pass the `data` to them (since the data never changes).

Here is the updated Plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/UzFnmxC80ThA5VeGmFek?p=preview